# Google Apps .NET Client

Tags: c#, google-api

I was googling after a Google Apps API .NET client and found the [following one](https://developers.google.com/gdata/client-cs) which seems rather old.

The Google Data page (which is the API that the mention client uses) states the following:

> Most newer Google APIs are not Google Data APIs. The Google Data APIs documentation applies only to the older APIs that are listed in the Google Data APIs directory. For information about a specific new API, see that API's documentation. For information about authorizing requests with a newer API, see Google Accounts Authentication and Authorization.

Does that mean that the Google Data APIs will be obsoleted?

Should I use another API/Client instead?

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/ (newest API) does not list any .NET client implementations.

Comment: @DaveHillier: I was looking for a .NET client and not asking about if the Google Data api will be obsoleted. If there are a newer api/client I rather be using that. If not, i rather use the new API directly than using an client for an obsolete API.

Comment: Your question still isn't very clear.

Comment: @DaveHillier: You're comment isn't very clear either. What are you not understanding?

Comment: What is your main question? You have two sentences with question marks, neither are particularly good questions. Are you trying to find the best .NET Google Apps API? If so what are your criteria?

Comment: My criteria is to find one which uses the most recent API version (i.e. still being maintained/updated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Contacts API v3 is still a Google Data API and as such it is supported by the .NET library for the Google Data API:

http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/

The documentation at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/ has examples in .NET to help you get started with that.

Just to clarify, the Contacts API v3 and Google Data APIs in general are not obsolete, however it is likely that new versions of them (or new APIs) will be be JSON-based instead and use the new client libraries.